# A convenient variable change for solving an integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to compute the following integral:

$$ \int_0^1\int_{x^2}^x  (x^2+y^2)^{\frac{-1}{2}} \, dy dx$$

I already noted that this is the region between the parabola $y=x^2$ and the line $y=x$, so it is clear that there should be a convenient variable change to simplify this integral. I wanted to ask for suggestions.

Comment: $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$ and the Jacobian is $dxdy\mapsto rdrd\theta$

Comment: That would be polar coordinates, what values would $\theta$ be within?

Comment: You don't have the change the bounds. Integrate and convert back if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\begin{cases}x=r\cos\theta\\y=r\sin\theta\end{cases}$$

$${}$$

$$\begin{cases}\;\overbrace{r^2\cos^2\theta}^{=x^2}\le \overbrace{r\sin\theta}^{=y}\le \overbrace{r\cos\theta}^{=x}\stackrel{\div r}\implies r\cos^2\theta\le\sin\theta\le\cos\theta\\{}\\0\le\theta\le\frac\pi4\end{cases}:$$

$$\int\limits_0^{\pi/4}d\theta\int\limits_0^{\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos^2\theta}} dr=\int\limits_0^{\pi/4}\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos^2\theta}=\left.\frac1{\cos\theta}\right|_0^{\pi/4}=\sqrt2-1$$